# wxPython Phoenix DataViewTreeControl() has "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: python, wxpython

I am new to wxPython and am trying to add a DataViewTreeControl. The control shows up just fine. However, when I associate data I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I have done enough work to know that it happens every time when it is trying to return from the `GetValue()` method.

I have patterned my implementation after the [Data View Model Demo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/DVC_DataViewModel.py) and I believe that it is done properly.

I have read that incorrectly trying to update objects can cause this kind of error ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537418/wxpython-crashes-with-segmentation-fault)) but I do not believe I am doing this. I have attempted using `wx.CallAfter()` and `wx.CallLater()` without luck.

The application does have a toolbar and grid currently working so I know the whole thing isn't broken.

If I leave the implementation as in the demo above the segmentation fault occurs when attempting the `return mapper[col]` (equivalent to line 180 in the demo) in this case the type of `mapper[col]` is `'unicode'`.

If I convert the value to string (this is what my column data type is set to be) then I get further before the seg fault occurs on line 16 below (I am not sure if this is important or not, but here it is):

```
    > /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py(16)decode()
     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):
---> 16     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
```

I am looking for some direction regarding whether this is likely a threading issue or if it might be an error with my implementation of the data model.

As I said this works until I try to associate a model with the control. Here is a minimum non-working example (self, in this case is the wx.Frame) :

```
def get_metadata(self):
    mdDict = dict()

    a1 = coremetadata.mdCoreAttribute(0, 'att1', 'cat1', 1, 'core1')
    a2 = coremetadata.mdCoreAttribute(1, 'att2', 'cat1', 2, 'core1')
    a3 = coremetadata.mdCoreAttribute(2, 'att3', 'cat3', 3, 'core1')

    c1 = coremetadata.mdCore('core1')
    c1.atts.append(a1)
    c1.atts.append(a2)
    c1.atts.append(a3)
    mdDict['core1'] = c1

    return coremetadata.CoreMetaData(mdDict.values())

def createDVTC(self):
    self.dvtc = dv.DataViewTreeCtrl(self.grid, wx.ID_ANY, size=(300,300))

    mdata = self.get_metadata()
    # tell the object to use our data
    self.dvtc.AssociateModel(mdata)

    return self.dvtc

def create_mdPane(self):

    self.dvtc = self.createDVTC()

    self._mgr.AddPane(self.dvtc, aui.AuiPaneInfo().
                      Name("MDNotebook").Caption("Metadata Display").
                      Right().Layer(1).Position(1).MinimizeButton(True))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: My ListView crashed this way when I set the data for a non-existing column.

Comment: @PetrBlahos Is it necessary to define columns in order to use `AssociateModel()`? Even if it is I have defined columns (I am sure they exist) and still have the problem.

Comment: Look, I have no idea. I just mentioned what happened to me, and that it might be related to your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was NOT a threading issue. It was my implementation of the model. Careful care has to be taken in order to return the appropriate data types (using `ObjectToItem()`) in the `GetParent()` and `GetChildren()` functions.

Specifically, I was not using `ObjectToItem()` in the `GetParent()` function...

Something pretty basic, but when the only feedback is a Segmentation Fault it isn't very easy to find.